# Configure usenet peers

Tags: usenet

I want to setup my own usenet server on a low powered home system. I went through the setup guides and stuffs.

What I would like to know is :

A list of usenet servers whom I can configure as peers to receive messages from and send to.
I might also be interested in posts from alt.binaries.* .. So are there any **servers free** which I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware, Usenet is a subscription service -- Atleast most of the more popular communities.

You can get cheap subscriptions from various online providers which will give you access to the content on the newsgroups.

> I might also be interested in posts from alt.binaries.*

From this, I undestand that you'd be interested in mirroring the content. I really don't recommend this due to the insane amount of information that is posted on the more active groups daily. You'd need a VERY fast internet connection and industrial-level storage.

Now, if all you want is to access some of the posted content, simply get a subscription from one of the many providers, download SABNZbd+ and use online usenet search engines to find content.

Good luck!